# MacBook Pro issue with Youtube videos

Tags: flash, macbook-pro, youtube

Opening videos to full screen does not work on my MacBook Pro. I have tried searching for solutions, watched demonstration videos to what might be causing this, the only way I can open a video to full screen on certain videos is if I right-click the video and choose pop out option.

Why is this happening and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Which Browser are you using? Which Operating System Version? OS X 10.?

Answer (score -1):

My experience is that MacOS, Adobe Flash and Chrome do not work very well together, as there is a conflict between build-in flash plugin and the official plugin.

I always use **Safari** for Flash Videos and most of the time works (much better than other browsers).

When your problem is only with YouTube, maybe try once the **[HTML5 version of Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/html5)** (without flash involved).

Comment: There's usually no reason to install the 'official' version of Flash, since Chrome includes it now.

Comment: That's correct, but people who already installed the "official" version can have problems, because both plugins are in the chrome config. But this is only a problem in chrome. As long as we do not know which broswer Paul is speaking of we can't tell more. Because of that my "basic" answer.

Answer (score -1):

For best experience of accessing YouTube videos, try using Safari. 
Safari allows you to do full screen and ignores power settings so screen won't auto dim or get lock.

Chrome has flash in inbuilt , which works nicely too.

Firefox is stable, requires adobe flash player installed ( if not done already). It's very stable.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's trying to make the video full screen. He doesn't say anything about power options or alternative browsers.

Comment: He wants to watch video in full screen, I suggested different browsers which allows to access the videos in full screen mode.

Comment: Most (if not all) browsers support full screen mode. The one he's already using likely does, and he's experiencing problems with it. While using a completely different browser may solve the problem, it isn't a direct answer to his question of why the browser he's already using isn't working properly.

Comment: In this case, he didn't mention name of the browser name so we can safely assume that browsers might be either safari , Firefox or chrome which is commonly used.